# Compilation error when updating to Veins 5

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have installed Veins 5 with Omnet++ 5.4.1. I upgraded my veins 4 project to veins 5 as advised [here](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/upgrading/)

But, I am facing a new problem where the compiler cannot see Veins library. The error I am getting is as follow: undefined reference to `Veins::DemoBaseApplLayer::initialize(int)`

I also included veins as a reference project and updated included path in the Makemake option to

> "C:\veins5\veins-veins-5a1\src"

Am I missing any further configuration?

I am running Veins under Windows OS.

Comment: Have you removed old compilation artifacts from your build folders (e.g., using `Project > Clean...` and selecting `Clean all Projects` in the OMNeT++ IDE)? Also, are you getting an error while building Veins or while building your simulation? If the latter, you might try running `make V=1` instead of `make` to compile your project. This will allow you to see what libraries are being linked (last line beginning with `clang++` or `g++`)

Comment: Veins compiles successfully and the example simulation that comes with it works fine as well. 
I use make V=1 and it seems that the libraries are linked. It shows that Veins libraries are linked. Part of the output is:
clang++ -shared  -o ... /veins5/veins-veins-5a1/src  -lveins -Wl,- rpath,C:/veins5/veins-veins-5a1/src ...

Answer (score 0):

The `DemoBaseApplLayer` of Veins 5 alpha 1 is not prepared to be used as a base class of other simulations' application layers. This can be rectified by changing its source code as follows:

In `src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.h`, line 56, change

```
class DemoBaseApplLayer : public BaseApplLayer {
```

to

```
class VEINS_API DemoBaseApplLayer : public BaseApplLayer {
```